# 3d Software middle mouse and mbp trackpad

Tags: macbook, mouse, 3d-modeling

So I am trying to learn some 3d modeling and have trouble in the oddest and most inconvenient of places. It looks like all the 3d software out there uses middle mouse click, and middle mouse click and drag for key functions. This is a problem because I am on a macbook with a trackpad. Right click and left click are not an issue, just middle.

Any ideas? Nothing has worked well so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs you can try:

- http://magicprefs.com
- http://www.jitouch.com
- http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/middleclick-for-mountain-lion